# How can I report on test results and group them by feature number using maven/junit/spock?

Tags: java, maven, junit, teamcity, spock

When adding tests for a feature, I'd like to mark the test with the story number for which it was created.

Right now, I can indirectly do this with a git commit.  However, I'd like to be more explicit, and possibly report on test success by issue.

Imagine answering the questions:
"Did the new tests for Story-702 succeed?  How many were added?"

This question is out of scope for our purposes:
"Were there any regressions for Story-702?"  That is answered by the regular build process.

My initial thought is to tag the tests in some way (either with an annotation or naming convention), and then parse that in some manner from the test result data.

Is there some feature of spock/junit/teamcity that would readily support this data request?

Comment: what about include story id into a test class name? like: TestStory_702

Comment: Yeah, though, then I'd have to build a parser, I was hoping for something pre-existing.

Comment: Is this something you are looking for? http://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/lang/Issue.html

Comment: That Spock Annotation looks pretty cool, I wonder if I can use it across Spock and Junit.  I'll have to test it out.

Answer (score 1):

[Allure framework](http://allure.qatools.ru) provides the specific annotations, for instance `@Issue("ISSUE-1")`, for generating the corresponding reports for the test results.

Comment: That looks very interesting.  I'll check it out.